# Code working unexpectedly after hosting in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, iis-10

Below is the code to build a cache which stores (typeName,type) found in the assemblies loaded in the current app domain.

I am facing this weird issue when trying to load types from one particular assembly say assemblyK. The assemblyK has around 954 types. Logs are in sync and it works all well when locally hosted in Visual Studio. Also, when I deploy the website in IIS it works well in when the buildCache is called for the first time.

However when the application pool is restarted/ after calling it later, it runs the nested loop for only for 5 types and goes on to execute the next function i.e. it does not throw any exception and moves forward.

```
private static void BuildCache()
{
    Assembly[] assemblies= AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

    foreach(Assembly assembly in assemblies){

    if(assembly.GlobalAssemblyCache){
    if(assemblly.ToString().Contains("assemblyK"))
    Logger.Log("GAC");
    continue;
    }
    try
    {
    if(assembly.ToString().Contains("AssemblyK"))
    {
    string allTypes = string.Join(",",assembly.GetTypes().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray())
    Logger.Log("All types :{0}",allTypes);
    }

    foreach(Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
      if(assembly.ToString().Contains("AssemblyK"))
    {
    Logger.Log("Type parsed :{0}",type);
    }
    if(!typeCache.ContainsKey(type.FullName))
    {
     if(assembly.ToString().Contains("AssemblyK"))
    {
    Logger.Log("Adding to cache :{0}",type);
    }
    typeCache.Add(type.FullName,type);
    }        
    } 
catch(Exception ex)
{
Logger.Log("Exception Caught : {0}",ex.ToString());
} 
}
```

}

Notably, The AssemblyK.dll build in Visual Studio 2008 in .Net 3.5 version works all well and when complied in Visual Studio 2019 causing the issue. Application Pool is 2.0. And the assemblyK is loaded in the "assemblies" always. Please Help.

P.S.: I copied the logs for allTypes received in both the cases(when it works and doesnt) in two files and did a file compare using cmd, with fc file1 file2. 
Both contained the identical data i.e.954 types. So my question is how can the foreach run randomly? What could be the issue here?

Update : The logs read:

1) **In Working case** :
All Types : Type1,Type2,Type3,..Type954

Type Parsed 954 times

Adding to cache 954 times

2) **In Not Working case** :
All Types : Type1,Type2,Type3,..Type954.

Type Pased 4 Times.

*typeCache is a private static readonly Dictionary*

Comment: So to summarize, the cache works if AsseblyK is compiled with VS2008 but doesn't when it's compiled with VS2019?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. It does work well in the first go though i.e. when i build in VS 2019 and paste it in bin and later doesnt.
he point that I could not comprehend is how can it skip the rest of the types in the for loop.

Comment: I suggest you post a complete working sample, how's typeCache defined? there are compile errors(contains -> Contains, toString -> ToString) etc.), what is the log output? I guess in the non working version "Adding to cache" is not logged?

Comment: Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine and your issue might come down to you doing it wrong. `catch(Exception ex)` is going on after Fatal exceptions, wich is a cardinal sin of exception handling. With that I asume you got similar issues elsehwere in the code, wich might be hiding your real issues. Here are two articles on exception handling that I link often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: Updated the question as per your suggestions @VentsyslavRaikov and you are right it is not logged along with the type parsed after 5 types.

Comment: @Specter123 - your code still doesn't compile(toString, join etc), you should provide working sample. Also the logic is incorrect - if typeCache.ContainsKey(type.FullName) -> typeCache.Add(type.FullName,type)

Comment: Thanks for the links @Christopher. Since the next functions (those follow it)  are executed as expected, others are ruled out but the fatal exceptions. Do you know any way by which i can confirm this?

Comment: Since the code is in the clients machine i have typed the code out here and hence had compilation errors. Updated.@VentsyslavRaikov.

Comment: @Specter123: Swallowing one Fatal exception leads to more - and less understandable - followup exceptions/behavior. Say you swallow a OutOfMemory while creating an array. Trying to access the array now can totally cause you a Memory Violation exception. The exact kind of issues the .NET Developers went out of their way to avoid. The exact issue Arrays are designed to avoid. Simply because the values were left in a unuseable state with the asumption nobody would catch it and thus it would never be used.